Existence of Primary operators in CFT
I'm currently studying the "TASI Lectures on the Conformal Bootstrap"(https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.07982, beginning of chapter 4.3). There the author states that the scaling dimension $\Delta$ of operators should be bounded from below in physically sensible theories. Then it's shown that if $\mathcal O(0)$ is an operator with scaling dimension $\Delta$, then $[K_\mu,\mathcal O(0)]$ is an operator with scaling dimension $(\Delta-1)$, which means $$[D,[K_\mu,\mathcal O(0)]] = (\Delta -1) [K_\mu,\mathcal O(0)].$$
Therefore the author concludes, that there must exist some operator $\mathcal O(0)$ that is a primary, so $$[K_\mu,\mathcal O(0)] = 0$$
such that this process terminates at some point and the scaling dimension can't be lowered arbitrary.
However if my calculation is correct, for an operator $\mathcal O(0)$ with scaling dimension $\Delta$, the operator $K_\mu\mathcal O(0)$ has scaling dimension $(\Delta -1)$, since $$[D,K_\mu\mathcal O(0)] = K_\mu [D,\mathcal O(0)] + [D,K_\mu]\mathcal O(0) = (\Delta -1) K_\mu\mathcal O(0).$$ This would show, that even if $\mathcal O(0)$ is a primary, its scaling dimension could be lowered arbitrary by just applying $K_\mu$.
So my question is, what is faulty here?

chapter, page equation numbers? perhaps link to reference?

The $K_{\mu}$ annihilates the operator $\mathcal{O}$, hence $K_{\mu}\mathcal{O}$ is not a eigenvector of $D$, and so the your last equation is $0=0$ rather than an equation to read off the scaling dimension

@TwoBs why would $K_\mu$ annihilate $\mathcal O$, the only information that we have is $[K_\mu,\mathcal O]=0$, which clearly doesn't imply $K_\mu\mathcal O = 0$, right?

The action of $K_{\mu}$ on $\mathcal{O}$ is defined via the commutation. (And your last equation  is the same of the first one)

@TwoBs in a some quantization, $K_\mu$ and $\mathcal O$ are operators acting on some hilbert space. So you can simply take their product, which is simply $K_\mu\mathcal O$. This is again an operator. I'm referring to this opetator, which is clearly not equal to the commutator.

I suspect the problem is that $\mathcal{O}(0)$ is not an operator on a Hilbert space (it would give an infinite norm state via translation invariance). Can you  make  your argument sharp  for an actual operator, e.g. $\mathcal{O}(x)$ possibly smeared over arbitrary test functions? I think it’s best thinking directly in terms of correlation func. of operators as the Tasi lectures show that inserting a operator in there is equivalent to calculate commutators (as long as the vacuum is invariant). The algebra of operator should be all you need to calculate the effect on the Hilbert space.

Just redo your last calculation except for $[D, [K_\mu, \mathcal{O}(0)]]$ and use the Jacobi identity.

The correct statement is that the scaling dimension of all local operators should be bounded below, and the issue is that $K_\mu {\cal O}(0)$ is not a local operator.  You are correct that $K_\mu$ can be used to make operators of arbitrarily low scaling dimension, in fact the simplest example of this is just to take ${\cal O}(0)$ to be a constant (the `identity' operator ${\cal O}(0)=1$), in which case $K_\mu {\cal O}(0) = K_\mu$. And indeed, $(K_\mu)^n$ has dimension $\Delta=-n$.  In 2d CFTs, there are an infinite number of conformal generators, usually denoted $L_n$ for all integer $n$, and they have scaling dimension $\Delta=-n$, and therefore are negative for $n>0$.  Again, the reason this is okay is that they are not local operators.
The basic reason that local operators have to have a lower bound on their scaling dimension is that there is a one-to-one mapping between local operators and states when you quantize the theory on a sphere (the `state-operator correspondence' of radial quantization).  This map in the direction from operators to states is simple: the state is just ${\cal O}(0)| {\rm vac} \rangle$, where $|{\rm vac}\rangle$ is the vacuum in radial quantization.  However, if you act on the vacuum with a nonlocal operator like $K_\mu$, it doesn't have to create a state.  In fact, the statement that the theory is conformally invariant means that the vacuum is invariant under conformal transformations, which implies $K_\mu | {\rm vac} \rangle=0$, so $K_\mu$ acting on the vacuum clearly does not create a state. Now you can also see that for a primary operator ${\cal O}(x)$, the operator $K_\mu {\cal O}(0)$ acting on the vacuum does not create a state, because
$$ K_\mu {\cal O}(0) | {\rm vac} \rangle = ([K_\mu, {\cal O}(0) ] + {\cal O}(0) K_\mu)| {\rm vac} \rangle = 0 + 0$$
since $[K_\mu, {\cal O}(0) ]=0$ and $K_\mu | {\rm vac} \rangle=0$.
